# How to deal with correlation in spectral data?

Tags: correlation, spectral-analysis, chemometrics

Currently I'm tasked with analysing data taken with optical emission spectroscopy (OES).
These measurements serve the purpose of identifying regions on the sample rich in certain chemical elements (species). The end result should be a "map" of the sample for each species showing its concentration. There can be a mix of different species.

The measurement data consists of an optical spectrum (intensity in arbitrary units over light wavelength in nm) for each point in a cartesian grid.
The raw data is structured with the columns [x, y, z, 200nm, 201nm, ..., 600nm) and one measurement of a single point per row.

Since the raw data is multiple GB per sample we use a common approach for data reduction in OES analysis of defining region of interests (ROI).
Each ROI is defined by setting an area around a peak in the signal, integrating it, and a background region, that subtracts from the ROI.
There are ROIs that are characteristic for each species.

Usually you'd define a few well-selected ROIs for your type of sample, however since this is explorative analysis for unknown samples, we defined many many ROIs.
That means some ROIs overlap with ROIs for other species (think you can't differentiate a peak at 400nm if both iron and aluminium have characteristic peaks at that wavelength) and also the backgrounds for ROIs are skewed by unforeseen peaks of other species.

Running a correlation analysis over all ROIs I would expect for the ROIs of the same species to have high correlation, and for the ROIs of different species to have correlation of near 0.
When looking at the correlation between same-species ROIs, for some species they behave well, for some they are quite poor:
[image]

In terms of correlation between different species there will be some ROIs to have high correlation, and indeed there are:
[image]

Now obviously the ROIs with high correlation to other-species-ROIs lead to false positives and should be removed.
Similarly ROIs with low correlation to same-species-ROIs lead to false negatives and should be eliminated as well.
Additionally, since for the end result I don't want to plot each ROI but aggregate all ROIs for each species, I'm looking for a way to unite them (maybe min-max-normalize each ROI, then sum?).
But mostly I'm struggling with a strategy to automatically drop the appropriate ROIs.

Also I'm not entirely sure how the ROI values influence the results.
For an ROI's background definition there could be another species' peak in it, resulting in a falsely high background, sometimes even higher than the peak of interest, leading to a negative ROI value.
Physically only positive values make sense (an intensity can't be negative).
How could I deal with these?
Should I clip negative values to 0?
Should I immediately eliminate ROIs that have some negative values?